# Export values to excel with multiple sheets

Tags: c#

In the below code i have excel writer when i export values only one sheet is available to store values i want multiple sheets to store values.Pls help me to do this.

```
string SheetName="";//I am Getting values using Forloop i want to create each sheet.
 using (Helper.ExcelWriter writer = new Helper.ExcelWriter(strFilePath))
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartDocument();
                            // Write the worksheet contents
                            writer.WriteStartWorksheet(SheetName);
                            //Write header row
                            writer.WriteStartRow();
//code
  writer.WriteEndRow();
 }

                            // Close up the document
                            writer.WriteEndWorksheet();
                            writer.WriteEndDocument();
                            writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample, how can you add multiple sheets in excel workbook with c#.

First you have to import `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` as reference.

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
if (xlApp == null)
{
   System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
   return;
}

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;


//After creating the new Workbook, next step is to write content to worksheet

 xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
//Bind your columns and rows as you like in the worksheet. For example : 
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Column 1, Row 1 data ";

//Then re initiate the xlworksheet and do the same as before.
xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Column 1, Row 1 data ";// 2nd sheet data

//Save the excel file after creating as much sheet you want.
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(path + "\\" + exlFilename); // here the path/ location and the filename to be provided.
```